# A slider doesn't change a value in a 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider

Here's my issue : I want to create a subplot of a plane that can be modified by a slider. The equation of the plane is *Z = 0.X + 0.Y + h* and I want to modify *h*.

The error in the terminal :

> `Exception in Tkinter callback
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1437, in __call__
>       return self.func(*args)
>     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 286, in button_press_event
>       FigureCanvasBase.button_press_event(self, x, y, num, guiEvent=event)
>     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1632, in button_press_event
>       self.callbacks.process(s, mouseevent)
>     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 262, in process
>       proxy(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 192, in __call__
>       return mtd(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/widgets.py", line 315, in _update
>       self.set_val(val)
>     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/widgets.py", line 327, in set_val
>       func(val)
>     File "/home/echos/lagrelle/Stage/Divers/cone.py", line 55, in update
>       l.set_zdata(0*X+0*Y+h)          # here's the problem !
>   AttributeError: 'Poly3DCollection' object has no attribute 'set_zdata'`

Don't mind the left subplot, *a priori* this is not linked to the problem. So here's the code :

```
""" ---------------------- LIBRAIRIES -------------------------- """

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons


plt.close('all')                        #close the previous figures

fig = plt.figure()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)                #create a little space for the slider

""" ------------------------ The Cone -------------------------- """

ax = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')          #create the space for the first window (the cone)


X= np.arange(-50,50,2)
Y=np.arange(-50,50,2)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)

Z = np.sqrt((X**2+Y**2)/(np.tan(np.pi/120)))            #Cone equation
ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z, rstride=3, cstride=3)          #Cone plot : wire frame
plt.axis('scaled')

""" ---------------------- The Plane ---------------------------- """

h0=0

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')         #create the space for the 2nd window (the plane)

Z2 = 0*X+0*Y+h0                         #Plane equation

l=ax2.plot_surface(X,Y,Z2,color='red',rstride=2, cstride=2) #Plane plot


""" -------------- The slider ---------------------- """

axhauteur = plt.axes([0.2, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])            #dimensions of the slider
shauteur = Slider(axhauteur, 'Hauteur', 0.5, 10.0, valinit=h0)  #caracteristics of the slider : from h0 (=0) to 10.0 with a pitch of 0.5

def update(val):                # function defining the slider

    h = shauteur.val                #
    l.set_zdata(0*X+0*Y+h)          # here's the problem ! 
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()          #
shauteur.on_changed(update)         #


plt.show()
```

Thank you, 
QL

Comment: Which line ? . Please paste the whole error message

Comment: @Abhimanyusingh  I'v edited the question

Comment: A bit of a workaround is to clear the axis using `ax2.cla()` and then redraw it using the updated value.

Comment: Am new to Matplot lib , but from python perspective , I would suggest try `print dir(l)` to get a list of supported attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct `set_data` method to update the surface plot.
The surface plot itself is a `Poly3DCollection`. This could in principle be updated using `.set_verts(verts)`. However, the `verts` would need to be points on a path. You may try to calculate them yourself, but I guess an easier solution is to simply redraw the surface plot, i.e. clear the axes (`ax.clear()` and create a new surface plot (`plot_surface(X,Y,0*X+0*Y+h)`).

Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons


fig = plt.figure()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)                
ax = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')        
X= np.arange(-50,50,2)
Y=np.arange(-50,50,2)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)

Z = np.sqrt((X**2+Y**2)/(np.tan(np.pi/120)))            
ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z, rstride=3, cstride=3)         
plt.axis('scaled')

h0=0

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d') 
Z2 = 0*X+0*Y+h0         

l=ax2.plot_surface(X,Y,Z2,color='red',rstride=2, cstride=2)

axhauteur = plt.axes([0.2, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
shauteur = Slider(axhauteur, 'Hauteur', 0.5, 10.0, valinit=h0)

def update(val): 
    h = shauteur.val 
    ax2.clear()
    l=ax2.plot_surface(X,Y,0*X+0*Y+h,color='red',rstride=2, cstride=2)
    ax2.set_zlim(0,10)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle() 
shauteur.on_changed(update)
ax2.set_zlim(0,10)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you.
I was exactly trying to bypass this issue by redrawing it.

Then, a big thx !